# 3DS max scrip python

Tags: python, helper, software-design, autodesk, 3dsmax

I'm trying to run this script within 3DS MAX, does anyone know the error that is happening here?        python.ExecuteFile "C:\Users\Asafe\Documents\Megascans Library\support\plugins\max\5.5\MSLiveLink\MS_API.py"

RESOLUT for my question!